# Как обратиться к функциям python в javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

Вот у меня есть файл index.py в одной директории с index.js файлом, допустим index.py такой:

```
def sum(a,b):
  return a + b
```

Как можно обратиться к этой функции в index.js файле? запустить, передать параметры, получить результат и т.д.

Comment: Если это не "разово", я бы думал в сторону поднятия на python websocket сервера, а с приложении nodejs сделал бы обращения как "клиент" получая/передавая информацию при помощи json

Comment: Сами файлы ничего не решают... Вопрос в том кто те файлы "запустил на исполнение"?

Comment: index.js как планируетca запускать?

Comment: Любая клиент-серверная связь.

Comment: Вообще, если логика совсем базовая, то можно использовать [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/), с другой стороны, если логика совсем базовая, то почему бы не написать на JavaScript?